# How to print string with embedded whitespace in python3

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

Assume the following string:

```
s = '\r\nthis is the second line\r\n\tthis line is indented\r\n'
```

If I run Python (v. 3.8.6) interactively, printing this string works as expected:

```
>>> print(s)

this is the second line
        this line is indented

>>>
```

But when I print this string to a file (ie, `print(s, file = "string.txt")`), the embedded whitespace is not interpreted and the text file contains the string literally (with "\t" instead of a tab, etc).

How can I get the same interactive output written to file?  Attempts using `str()`, f-strings, and `format()` were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
with open('file.txt','w') as file:
  print('\r\nthis is the second line\r\n\tthis line is indentedd\r\n',file=file)
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I initially attempted without success.  

In my actual code, the string is actually a key in a dictionary and was put together by concatenating several strings parsed from a CSV file that was read in earlier code.  I don’t think that matters but just providing full disclosure.